# Best practices for collating and analysing client feedback from multiple departments

Tags: product-owner, clients, feedback, innovation

What is an effective way to collate and analyse validation feedback for new products from our clients. In our organisation, validation feedback is gathered by team members from various departments, including sales, customer service, and product development, making it a challenge to ensure consistency in how this information is recorded and analysed.

Importantly, all the feedback we collect is stored in Pipedrive, our CRM. Despite this, we're facing difficulties in making the best use of this data to drive new products. Recently we have adopted the 'Mom Test' style of product validation so are asking more fluid style questions which makes it more difficult to analyse.

The diversity in the sources of feedback and the involvement of multiple departments have presented challenges in centralising and effectively analysing this information.